# Web services using Soap and rest services

Tags: web-services

I built a web service using soap can i consume that service in another application using Rest Services that is by using get or Post Http methods?
Like wise  Can i consume service using soap that is  build using Rest

Answer (score 0):

Both REST and SOAP protocols are published and consumed over HTTP. SOAP adds a layer on top of it for encoding data, that is not used on REST services nor clients.

So, for SOAP services use a SOAP client, and for REST services use a REST client. However, if you need to integrate different types of services, you could build an app that has both REST and SOAP clients, and publishes the result either as a SOAP service, a REST service, or both.